# How to change cell colors as time passes

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a simple spreadsheet where column B will only be times of a day. I would like for the color of the cells in this column to change based on amount of time lapsed.

For example, the cell says 10AM and it is currently 12:30PM I would like for the cell to be green.
After 12 hours of lapsed time the cell needs to be yellow - and after 18 hours, red.

I have tried several methods but can't seem to figure this one out.

In conditional formatting, I tried several versions of NOW() and I'm lost

Comment: just realize that NOW() while it is volatile it still needs something in excel to change to kick the recalc.  Excel just does not recalc automatically with no changes being made by a user or code.  So using something like `=NOW()>A1+TIME(12,0,0)` will not automatically recalc unless a change is made in excel that triggers the recalc.  The passing of time itself is not a trigger.

Comment: What "versions" of now()? you can apply formatting to it to get long date, short date or time like hours, minutes but "versions:?

Comment: Okay, learning that time passing itself it's a trigger is very helpful. Does this mean that it cannot be done?

Comment: I'm pretty confident you could have a VBA script trigger an intermittent update.  Perhaps someone with experience could tell you how, but a quick search gave some promising results if you're willing to go that route.